# Why does mpi message passing seem to speed up?

Tags: mpi, benchmarking

I'm learning to program MPI, and I made a simple program to pass a message back and forth. In the message I recorded the sending and receiving times (in nanoseconds), and I noticed something weird: the first few times it sent/received a message, there was a significant amount of delay (dozens of microseconds), although with more sends/receives, that delay disappeared and became only 1-2 microseconds. **Why does this happen?**

My program is running on a machine with four cores, and I'm calling the program with two of them. I've created a minimal example to demonstrate:

```
vector<size_t> times;
times.reserve(100);
stopwatch s;//Records time since initialization of value
int counter = 0;
if(mpi.world_rank == 0)
{
    //Do this if you're on thread 0
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
    {
        ++counter;
        times.push_back(s.age_nano());
        //Send counter (size of 1) to thread 1 with tag 0
        mpi.send(&counter, 1, 1, 0);
        //Receive value (size of 1) from thread 1 with tag 0
        mpi.receive(&counter, 1, 1, 0);
    }
}
else if(mpi.world_rank == 1)
{
    //Otherwise do this if you're on thread 1
    for(int i=0;i<20;++i)
    {
        //Receive value (size of 1) from thread 0 with tag 0
        mpi.receive(&counter, 1, 0, 0);
        ++counter;
        times.push_back(s.age_nano());
        //Send counter (size of 1) to thread 0 with tag 0
        mpi.send(&counter, 1, 0, 0);
    }
}
for(int i=times.size(); i > 0; --i) times[i] -= times[i-1];
cout << times << " Counter: " << counter << endl;
```

When I run the program I get the following output:

```
[Code]$ mpic++ main.cc && mpirun -n 2 a.out
{116, 32276, 1288, 665, 674, 633, 662, 661, 570, 651, 560, 564, 610, 602, 635, 636, 13511, 3080, 449, 473} Counter: 40
{23839, 9402, 908, 662, 668, 651, 652, 592, 635, 586, 593, 575, 632, 612, 632, 7120, 8585, 1435, 442, 450} Counter: 40
```

If you notice, some of the first few values are much higher than the other ones, most of which are between 500 and 700 nanoseconds. The `mpi.send` and `mpi.receive` functions are just a very light wrapper for more standard functions such as `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv`. Here's the code for the `stopwatch` class:

```
struct stopwatch
{
typedef decltype(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()) time;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1,1>> seconds;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> milliseconds;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::micro> microseconds;
typedef std::chrono::duration<double, std::nano> nanoseconds;
time _start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto age_nano()
{
    return (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _start).count();
}
double age_micro()
{
    return microseconds(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _start).count();
}
double age_milli()
{
    return milliseconds(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _start).count();
}
double age()
{
    return seconds(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - _start).count();
}
void reset() { _start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
};
```

And here's the code for the wrapper I built around mpi:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
template<class...> struct get_mpi_type{};
template<class T> struct get_mpi_type<const T>      { static constexpr auto type() { return get_mpi_type<T>::type(); } };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<short>               { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_SHORT; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<int>                 { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_INT; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<long int>            { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_LONG; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<long long int>       { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_LONG_LONG; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<unsigned char>       { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<unsigned short>      { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_UNSIGNED_SHORT; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<unsigned int>        { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_UNSIGNED; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<unsigned long int>   { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<unsigned long long int> { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<float>               { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_FLOAT; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<double>              { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_DOUBLE; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<long double>             { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_LONG_DOUBLE; }; };
template<> struct get_mpi_type<char>                { static constexpr auto type() { return MPI_BYTE; }; };
struct mpi_thread
{
int world_rank;
int world_size;
mpi_thread()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
}
~mpi_thread()
{
    MPI_Finalize();
}
template<class T> void send(const T* data, int count, int destination, int tag)
{
    MPI_Send(data, count, get_mpi_type<T>::type(), destination, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
template<class T> void send(const std::vector<T>& data, int destination, int tag)
{
    send(data.data(), data.size(), destination, tag);
}
template<class T> void send(const std::basic_string<T>& str, int destination, int tag)
{
    send(str.data(), str.size(), destination, tag);
}
MPI_Status probe(int source, int tag)
{
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Probe(source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    return status;
}
template<class T> int get_msg_size(MPI_Status& status)
{
    int num_amnt;
    MPI_Get_count(&status, get_mpi_type<T>::type(), &num_amnt);
    return num_amnt;
}

template<class T> void receive(T* data, int count, int source, int tag, MPI_Status& status = *MPI_STATUS_IGNORE)
{
    MPI_Recv(data, count, get_mpi_type<T>::type(), source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
template<class T> void receive(std::vector<T>& dest, int source, int tag)
{
    MPI_Status status = probe(source, tag);
    int size = get_msg_size<T>(status);
    dest.clear();
    dest.resize(size);
    receive(&dest[0], size, source, tag, status);
}
template<class T> void receive(std::basic_string<T>& dest, int source, int tag)
{
    MPI_Status status = probe(source, tag);
    int size = get_msg_size<T>(status);
    dest.clear();
    dest.resize(size);
    receive(&dest[0], size, source, tag, status);
}
} mpi;
```

Also I overloaded the `ostream <<` operator to print out vectors, but that's pretty basic.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to benchmark MPI, you should probably use well known benchmarks such as (Ohio State University) OSU benchmarks or Intel IMB.

some MPI libraries establish connections "on demand", that means the first time a message is sent to a peer, extra overhead is required to establish the connection. some overhead might also appears when you send a given memory region for the first time (memory has to be registered, and there is a cost for that).

well known benchmarks generally run a few warm-up iterations before doing the actual measurements, so that one-shot delays are hidden from the results.